# Check ADusers for property export-csv and include null

Tags: powershell

I have a list of mobile numbers that I want to try to match ad users with and then export as csv.

The current script works so far but I want it to include a row when it doesn't find a user which says the mobile number that it had no match from.

```
$ou="OU=User Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=dc01,DC=local"

get-content chk_usr_mobile.csv | 
ForEach {
$aduser=get-aduser -SearchBase $ou -filter{(mobile -eq $_)} -Properties *|
select -Property company,emailaddress,@{L='departmentnumber'; E={$_.departmentnumber[0]}}, mobile,givenname,sn
if ($aduser -eq $null){
$aduser=$_
}
else{
$aduser}
} | export-csv .\tel_result.csv -encoding UTF8 -notypeinformation
```

So the ouput I want should be like this in the csv:

```
"company","emailaddress","departmentnumber","mobile","givenname","sn"
"Company","user1g@company.com","123","123456789","Joe","Doe"
"no user found for number 98765431"
"Company","user2g@company.com","124","456789123","Jane","Doe"
```

Comment: `departmentnumber` is not a standard property for a AD user. Is the schema extended with this property in your environment?. P.S. The desired output is a broken CSV file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code, the input CSV file isn't a CSV file at all, but rather a text file with phone numbers each on a separate line..

In order to not break the output CSV, I suggest you do the following:

```
$ou="OU=User Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=dc01,DC=local"
Get-Content chk_usr_mobile.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $aduser = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter { mobile -eq $_ } -Properties Company,EmailAddress,departmentnumber,Mobile,GivenName,Surname
    if ($aduser) {
        $aduser | Select-Object Company,EmailAddress,@{L='DepartmentNumber'; E={$_.departmentnumber[0]}},Mobile,GivenName,Surname
    }
    else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Company = 'no user found for number {0}' -f $_
            EmailAddress = ''
            DepartmentNumber = ''
            Mobile = ''
            GivenName = ''
            Surname = ''
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv .\tel_result.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Correct it's just a texfile as input, didn't know it needed all values not to break the csv. Now it works great!

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the feedback!